# Does arbitrum / optimism / other L2s have MEV?

Tags: layer-2, arbitrum, mev

Due to the fact that the sequencer is the "real" node that sequences transactions, I would imagine that is the true MEVer...

But for example, could I run an Arbitrum node and MEV some transactions before passing them to the sequencer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Due to the fact that the sequencer is the "real" node that sequences transactions, I would imagine that is the true MEVer...

Correct.

> But for example, could I run an Arbitrum node and MEV some transactions before passing them to the sequencer?

You'd need a mempool for that, but txs on Arbitrum (and similar L2s) get forwarded straight to the sequencer. Here's an example on [Arbitrum Nitro](https://github.com/OffchainLabs/nitro/blob/af87ba29bc34c27bd4d85b3066a1cc3a759bab66/cmd/chaininfo/chain_info.go#L23).